# How to calculate integration of multiplying a series of functions in python

Tags: python, scipy, continuous-integration

I am trying to Calculate the following integration:

[image]

where p_{i} are values and x is the variable here, and suppose N=5.
I know solving this with sympy is challenging. Therefore I plan to solve it numerically with scipy package. But my question is how I can formulate this product functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate numerically using [scipy.integrate.quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
def f(x, p):
    return (1 - np.prod(1 - np.exp(-p * x))) / 5.0

# This reduces to exp(-x) for which you might know the answer.
p = np.array([1])
quad(f, 0.0, np.inf, args=p)

# a difficult example that I don't know how to calculate
# analytically
p = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
quad(f, 0.0, np.inf, args=p)
```

This method will give you the answer if all `p[i] > 0` with a reasonable margin.